# If $\sigma\in S_n$ is of length $n$, then $\sigma$ generates its centralizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $S_n$ and $C_G(\sigma)$ denote the [symmetric goup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) and the [centralizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer) of $\sigma\in S_n$, respectively. I want to show: If $\sigma$ is of length $n$, then $C_G(\sigma)=\langle\sigma\rangle$, i.e. $\sigma$ generates $C_G(\sigma)$

Comment: I switched “conjugacy class” with “centralizer.” Perhaps that confusion was the only problem. $\sigma = (1,2,3,4)$ does not generate its own conjugacy class in $S_4$, since it is conjugate to all six 4-cycles, but $\langle \sigma \rangle$ has only four elements (and $\sigma$ is only conjugate to two of them, $\sigma$ and $\sigma^3$).

Comment: @JackSchmidt - Indeed, I was confused about the two terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\langle \sigma \rangle \subset C_G(\sigma)$, so it is enough to show that they are the same size.

But how can we quickly compute the size of $C_G(\sigma)$?  The index of the centralizer is just the size of the conjugacy class of $\sigma$, or the number of $n$-cycles in $S_n$.